# Get Github notification if new PR matches filter

Tags: notifications, github

I want to be notified whenever a pull requests in a particular repo with a particular label gets created.

I know that I can

- look them up by [searching for `is:pr repo:USERNAME/REPOSITORY label:LABEL` in `github.com/pulls`](https://github.com/pulls?q=is%3Apr+repo%3AUSERNAME%2FREPOSITORY+label%3ALABEL)
- look them up by [searching for `label:LABEL` in `github.com/USERNAME/REPOSITORY/pulls`](https://github.com/USERNAME/REPOSITORY/pulls?q=label%3ALABEL)
- subscribe to the creation of ***any*** PR in a particular repo

but I don't know how to do what I want